# Making animated gifs using R

Tags: r, animated-gif

Does anyone have any tips regarding making animated GIFs in R? I'm trying to make some time lapse map GIFs.

Comment: @David_Arenburg this was marked duplicate and linked to another question, but that question is closed for being "too broad"...

Comment: https://www.programmingr.com/content/animations-r/#:~:text=Fortunately%2C%20creating%20animated%20graphs%20in%20R%20is%20fairly,graph%20with%20a%20couple%20of%20bells%20and%20whistles.

I created a gif using this code found here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Repeat Question** : Please see this previous StackOverflow question on [**creating a series of plots in R**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298100/creating-a-movie-from-a-series-of-plots-in-r) which offers a number of solutions including pointers to other useful packages such as the [**animation**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=animation) package.

Comment: FYI, suggested ways to handle duplicate questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-to-handle-duplicate-questions/10844#10844

Comment: Thanks for the hint -- will try to remember that next time :)

Answer (score 3):

Also be sure to check out the [animation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html) package

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just generating a series of png files (which happens by default each time you run `plot` with the `png` device open).  You can then combine them into an animated gif with another program such as ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [sample code](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/06/09/1365.html) of using Imagemagick (called through R) for any sequence of png's you generate.