# Plot points map of population

Tags: r, dictionary, cartography

I want to plot kind of isarhytmoc points [map](http://statistik-stuttgart.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/map-raw-1024x952.png) like in this [tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-isarithmic-maps-of-election-data-12/), but with population data.
However, unfortunately, I have no enough skill and only came with such code:

```
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
require(RColorBrewer)
require(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
require(gpclib)
gpclibPermitStatus() 
gpclibPermit()


rus<-url("http://www.filefactory.com/file/4h1hb5c1cw7r/n/RUS_adm1_RData")
print(load(rus))
proj4.str <- CRS("+init=epsg:3413 +lon_0=105")
gadm.prj <- spTransform(gadm, proj4.str)


popul <- read.csv2(file="C:\\unempl11.txt", header = TRUE, 
        sep = ";",quote = "", dec=",", stringsAsFactors=F)

df <- fortify(gadm.prj, region = "ID_1")
df2 <- merge(df, gadm.prj, by.x="id", by.y="ID_1")






p <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) +
       geom_point(data    = popul,  
                  mapping = aes(x=lon, y=lat, colour=abs),
                  size    = 3,
                  alpha   = 0.8) +
       scale_colour_gradient2(name  = "Population",
                              low   = "darkred",
                              mid   = "white",
                              high  = "blue",
                              guide = "colorbar") +
       ggtitle("Population in Russia)")
p + geom_path(data    = df2,
               mapping = aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
              size    = 0.125)
```

[Here is the data I use](http://files.mail.ru/D094C375C3AD4F81940A7F34D2247321), if anyone can help me with some ideas i will be grateful.

Comment: you have to pay to look at that data??

Comment: oops sorry. I edited, now http://files.mail.ru/D094C375C3AD4F81940A7F34D2247321

Comment: You are asking the same question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64288/plot-points-map-of-population

Comment: You are absolutely right as there are different people  visiting different resources and thus different answers may be given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to display points but you are using an
`SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` source. You can extract the coordinates
of the centroids with `coordinates` and use them as coordinates of
your data, but I am not sure if that is what you need:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

rus <- url("http://www.filefactory.com/file/4h1hb5c1cw7r/n/RUS_adm1_RData")
load(rus)
proj4.str <- CRS("+init=epsg:3413 +lon_0=105")
gadm.prj <- spTransform(gadm, proj4.str)
## IDs needed to match polygons and data
nms <- gadm.prj$NAME_1

ll <- coordinates(gadm.prj)
```

On the other hand, I cannot retrieve correctly the `data` column
of your file. I fill it with some noise:

```
popul <- read.csv2('/tmp/popul.txt')
popul$data <- runif(nrow(popul))
```

Now it's time to match coordinates and data (similar to what we
did in
[this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163670/animated-gadm-map-in-r/17180169#17180169)):

```
ord1 <- match(nms, popul$region)
popul <- popul[ord1,]
row.names(popul) <- nms
row.names(ll) <- nms

popSP <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(ll, popul["data"], proj4string=proj4.str)
```

This `SpatialPointsDataFrame` can be directly displayed with
`spplot` with the boundaries below using `sp.layout`.

```
spplot(popSP, sp.layout=list('sp.polygons', gadm.prj))
```

[image: result]