# Gadm map with points layer in R

Tags: r, dictionary, cartography

I [have already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278264/plot-points-map-of-population) about plotting points dependent on region, but now my question is about overlaying points given by coordinations over gadm map. I want to show different meteostations, using data based on this [site](http://www.tageo.com/index-e-rs-weather-rs-step-4.htm) or here is  [data used in code](http://files.mail.ru/FB13505A8F164ABF8BB18671DA89CC8F) I've tried using such code:

```
require(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gpclib)
library(rgeos)
library(PBSmapping)
gpclibPermit()
rus<-load("C://RUS_adm1.RData")
proj4.str <- CRS("+init=epsg:3413 +lon_0=105")
gadm.prj <- spTransform(gadm, proj4.str)
rus<-gadm.prj

met <- read.csv2('C:\\meteo.txt')


cds <- data.frame(
                  Longitude=met$Long,
                  Latitude=met$Lat)

k<-as.matrix(cds)



popSP <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=k,met["Elevation"], proj4string=proj4.str)

spplot(popSP, sp.layout=list('sp.polygons', gadm.prj))
```

, following advice from already mentioneed question, but it ends up with plotting points w/o gadm layer [image], I guess it's because of non-mentioning regions

Sorry, if question is dumb, but I will be grateful for any help

Comment: See this crosspost on gis.stackexchange.com for possible solutions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64448/overlay-points-over-gadm-map

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64448/overlay-points-over-gadm-map). Thanks to [flowla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977053/flowla)

Edited code a little bit, I could plot different plot according to elevation.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)


rus <- load("C://RUS_adm1.RData")

popSP <- met <- read.csv2("C://meteo.txt")
for (i in c(3, 4)) 
  popSP[, i] <- popSP[, i] / 1000

coordinates(popSP) <- ~ Long + Lat
projection(popSP) <- projection(gadm)

# Reprojection to EPSG:3413 (see http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3413/)
proj4.str <- CRS("+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=105 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

gadm.prj <- spTransform(gadm, proj4.str)
popSP.prj <- spTransform(popSP, proj4.str)






col_no <- as.factor(as.numeric(cut(popSP.prj$Elevation,
                    c(0,2500,5000,10000,15000,20000,100000))))


levels(col_no) <- c("<2500", "2500-5000","5000-10000", "10000-15000","15000-20000",">20000" )
color = rainbow(6)
popSP.prj$col_no<-col_no



spplot(popSP.prj, "col_no", sp.layout=list('sp.polygons',cols="ID_0", gadm.prj), col.regions=color, main="Meteostations in Russia", key.space="right")
```

[image: Plot]