# How to create movie from images?

Tags: r

I'd like to create a movie from images. I know create the images, but I don't know how get together it. Below it is a mwe.

```
setwd("...") #work space
x <- matrix(runif(20), ncol = 2)
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  name = paste('0',i,'plot.png', sep='')
  png(name)
  plot(x[i, 1], x[i,2], xlim = c(-1.5, 1.5), ylim = c(-1.5, 1.5))
  dev.off()
}
```

This questions is very similar with [Creating a Movie from a Series of Plots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298100/creating-a-movie-from-a-series-of-plots-in-r), but the links are outdated. And no solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Movie from a Series of Plots in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298100/creating-a-movie-from-a-series-of-plots-in-r)

Comment: Yes, but the links are outdated.